# Convert function pointer to std::uintptr_t at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I'd like to convert a constant expression function pointer to a `std::uintptr_t` at compile time.  How can I do this?

Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <cstdint>
void fn() {}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  constexpr void* ptr = (void *) fn;
  constexpr std::uintptr_t idx = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(fn);
  return 0;
}
```

GCC 7/8/9 are currently giving me the error "conversion from pointer type to arithmetic type `std::uintptr_t` in a constant expression."  However, my understanding was that `std::uintptr_t` should be able to hold any pointer type, meaning this should be able to be done in a constant expression.

**Background**

To give a bit of background as to why I need this, I want to (1) retrieve the address of a function pointer at compile time, (2) convert it to a `std::uintptr_t`, then (3) pass it as a template parameter so it can be baked into a function at compile time.

This is meant to be part of an RPC engine, similar to this code, which produces a very similar error:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

template <std::uintptr_t FnPtr, typename Fn>
void fn_handler() {
  ((Fn *) FnPtr)();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  auto lel = []() {
    printf("Hi, fam!\n");
  };
  // Note that +lel is an implement 0+lel, converting
  // the lambda to a fn ptr.
  constexpr void* ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(+lel);
  constexpr std::uintptr_t idx = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(ptr);

  fn_handler<idx, decltype(lel)>();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to go through the integer? function pointers can be template arguments themselves.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer demonstrating how to do this.  Just to be clear, I don't want to pass a function pointer as a templated function argument, I want to pass a function pointer *as a template parameter*, so that the `fn_handler` need not pass in a function pointer.

Comment: This is probably a [known GCC bug.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83258)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, my understanding was that std::uintptr_t should be able to hold any pointer type, meaning this should be able to be done in a constant expression.

Sure. But `reinterpret_cast` is *never* allowed in a constant expression. And since that's the only way to convert a pointer into an integer, that's not something you can do *at compile time*.

If you want to pass a function pointer as a template parameter, then [just do that](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sAiS__):

```
int func() {return 0;}

template<int (*pfn)()>
int fn_handler()
{
  return pfn();
}

...

fn_handler<&func>();
```

If you want to make the type of the function a template parameter, then pre-C++17, you can use the old trick like this:

```
template<typename Fn, Fn pfn>
decltype(auto) fn_handler()
{
  return pfn();
}

...

fn_handler<decltype(&func), &func>();
```

C++17 lets us just use `auto`:

```
template<auto pfn>
decltype(auto) fn_handler()
{
  return pfn();
}

...

fn_handler<&func>();
```